# Any slice of array java

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity

I tried to solve demo test in codility.
question:

> A non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers is given. A pair of integers (P, Q), such that 0 ≤ P ≤ Q < N, is called a slice of array A. The sum of a slice (P, Q) is the total of A[P] + A[P+1] + ... + A[Q].
>
> A min abs slice is a slice whose absolute sum is minimal.
>
> For example, array A such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 2
> A[1] = -4
> A[2] = 6
> A[3] = -3
> A[4] = 9
> ```
>
> contains the following slices, among others:
>
> ```
> (0, 1), whose absolute sum = |2 + (−4)| = 2
> (0, 2), whose absolute sum = |2 + (−4) + 6| = 4
> (0, 3), whose absolute sum = |2 + (−4) + 6 + (−3)| = 1
> (1, 3), whose absolute sum = |(−4) + 6 + (−3)| = 1
> (1, 4), whose absolute sum = |(−4) + 6 + (−3) + 9| = 8
> (4, 4), whose absolute sum = |9| = 9
> ```
>
> Both slices (0, 3) and (1, 3) are min abs slices and their absolute sum equals 1.

I tried to go over all slices and did something like this:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int N = A.length;
        if(N==1)
        {
            return A[0];
        }
        Arrays.sort(A);
        for(int i=0;i<N; ++i)
        {
            System.out.println(A[i]);
        }
        int tail = 0;
        int head = N - 1;
        System.out.println(tail+ " "+head+"first");
        long minAbsSum =(long) Math.abs(A[tail] + A[head]);
        while (tail <= head) {        
            System.out.println(tail+ " "+head);
            long currentSum = (long)A[tail] + (long)A[head];
            minAbsSum = (long)Math.min(minAbsSum, Math.abs(currentSum));
            // If the sum has become
            // positive, we should know that the head can be moved left
            if (currentSum <= 0)
                tail++;
            else
                head--;
        }
        return (int)minAbsSum;
    }
}
```

but I got slices of 2.

Is there some way that I could go over all the slices as requested in O(N*logN) complexity?

Comment: sorry, just edit my question.

Comment: Why there is `Arrays.sort(A);` in your code?

Comment: ya sorting won't give you a contiguous sequence ....

Comment: Your code looks like solution to some different problem which makes your question very unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question. This is the only approach to solution I have right now

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the right forum to get help with your assignments. This is about helping developers with problems they encounter during development.

Setting this aside, your question seems to be about an algorithm that finds the mininmal absolute sum for any given slice of the provided  array. As others have pointed out in the comments section, you "destroy" the sequence of values in your input array by sorting it. After the sorting you wont be able to reconstruct the sequence of values in the input array.

A possible solution with O(n^2) would be to iterate over all potential slices and remember the ones with the minimal absolute sum. To reduce the complexity to O(n log(n)) you could try to recursively split the input array into separate slices, calculate the sums for each and merge the results.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MinimalSliceSum {
    private static int[] values = { 2, -4, 6, -3, 9 };
    private static int minimalAbsSum = values[0];
    private static Set<Slice> minimalSlices = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < values.length; j++) {
                sum += values[j];
                processRange(i, j, sum);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Minimal abs sum: " + minimalAbsSum);
        for (Slice slice : minimalSlices) {
            System.out.println("Slice (" + slice.getFrom() + ", " + slice.getTo() + ")");
        }
    }

    private static void processRange(int i, int j, int sum) {
        int absSum = Math.abs(sum);
        if (minimalAbsSum > absSum) {
            minimalAbsSum = absSum;
            minimalSlices.clear();
        }
        if (minimalAbsSum == absSum) {
            minimalSlices.add(new Slice(i, j));
        }
    }

    public static class Slice {
        private int from;
        private int to;

        public Slice(int from, int to) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        public int getFrom() {
            return from;
        }

        public int getTo() {
            return to;
        }
    }
}
```